# Why isn't my city growing?

Tags: civilization-5

It is my first game of Civilization 5, but I have played Civilization 3 and 4 many times. Twice I have seen my capital having a stagnation for no apparent reason. From what I read food is the only reason a city would stagnate. I have even seen a city with more feed than required being in stagnation.

At this moment I have a source of 15 food and 12 are consumed by civilians, so this makes 3 extra food. As I understand it, there is no reason there should be a stagnation, but there is. 
I guess there is also a happiness factor, but my happiness is well above unhappiness.

What could cause that? Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whenever you build a Settler, all your extra food goes towards  increasing the production of that unit. Due to this your city will *always* be stagnant when you're building  a settler, and I'm willing to bet this is what is happening to you.

Comment: That must be it. Is it new to civ 5? I don't recall that issue in civ 4. And it would explain why a worker takes so long to build, even longer than a library which I recall was the opposite in civ4.

Comment: I can not recall whether it was in Civ 4 or not

Comment: @Wipq In Civ 5 this only applies to Settlers.  In Civ 4 it applied to both Settlers and Workers.

Comment: Note that the city AI takes no notice of the fact that you are building a settler, and carries on trying to churn out food. So it's usually worthwhile to change the city focus to Prodution while the settler is being built - it may speed up the settler, and will make no difference to city growth.

Answer (score 8):

There is an "**Avoid growth" option**, which prevents city from jumping to the next growth level. Maybe you selected it without knowing

The option is on your right panel, right at bottom of *Citizen Management* options.

[image: See "**Avoid growth**"]

See full detail here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ85c.jpg

Even though the city has enough food to grow it won't grow.

Comment: It actually does prevent growth

Comment: I am testing this after work. Since I remember it working the other way.

Comment: When I posted this, it worked this way, my city wasn't growing and it drove me nuts until I found that check. Could be it changed since then...

Comment: I just tested it during my break, and you are right.